# MongoDB sharding with repeated documents

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose, replication, sharding

I am new to mongodb and wish to create a distributed database environment using docker-compose with mongodb. I've created multiple docker with shards to simulate multiple sites. However, I have a problem to replicate the same set of documents into multiple shards.

For example I have a collection with a key that has value "A" and "B". I want to distribute this collection into 2 shards where

Shard 1 = A & B
Shard 2 = B only

However, when I run the balancer it distributes all A's into shard 1 and B's into shard 2. Is there any way I can do the sharding with repeated data or am I using the wrong approach for my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be approaching sharding (horizontal scaling) incorrectly.  What makes sharding in Mongo work is that the sharding *key* is chosen such that it results in (vertical) shards which have a roughly even distribution of data, or a similar number of Mongo documents.  A requirement of sharding which makes it work well is that queries would typically be directed to only a single shard.  If you have queries which need to return some field having the different values of A and B, then it implies that this field should *not* be the sharding key.  Queries can go across shards, but certain cross-shard operations, such as joins, can be very costly.  In your particular case, perhaps some other field could be used as sharding key.

Comment: I'm trying to make the shards act like different sites. For example site 1 queries will require key value A & B and site 2 queries only require key value B. Hence those queries are supposed to be directed to only one of the shards. Is there a better way to do this other than sharding?

Comment: See the other answer which actually seems to address your exact comment above.  One document exists in one shard, not multiple shards.

Answer (score 0):

Redundancy in MongoDB is provided by replica sets, not sharded clusters.

Each shard can be backed by a replica set with your desired number of nodes to provide the required redundancy level.

It is not possible to have the same document be (authoritatively) located in multiple shards.